# Retrieving video comment using GData youtube

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am using Youtube data API v2

I am getting the comments of videos using this URL

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/IukDWhf7U9I/comments?&start-index=1&max-results=20&v=2
```

now the issue is when i increase the limit

```
start-index=100
max-results=50
```

then it stops giving me the results.
where as number of comments of this video are almost 3000

how can i get them all. Now it is giving me 100 only.

Comment: can u please tell me how u downloaded gdata.framework

Comment: i have not download any framework this is just the webservices used to get information . i am using v2 API